# Sending image from iPhone to Mysql Database

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c, xcode

I'm able to send strings from my app to my remote database! I'm able to download images from database to my app and show they properly! But if I want send an image from the app to my database? I think that mysql expect a blob formate... I'm trying but I think is not the correct way

```
NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(theDataObject.immagineGestione);
[Base64 initialize];
NSString *strEncoded = [Base64 encode:data];

NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.xxxxxx-xo.nxx/Scrxxts/Evxxto/WIGixxxnto.php?image=%@",strEncoded];

NSData* dataUrl = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
```

My php file do not start!

```
 $image = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['image'], $database);

 $sql = "INSERT INTO annotazioni (immagine) values (file_get_contents($image))"

 mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Unless you have a really good reason for doing so, I would strongly advise against storing images in MySQL. What's wrong with storing the images in a file and just saving a URL in the database.

Comment: Ok but i think that Its the only solution for me... Its like insert an avatar for the own photo profile

Comment: Why can't you store the files elsewhere? MySQL is not designed to store photos.

Comment: How do you send strings to your remote database?